# protractor elementExplorer

Tags: angularjs, node.js, debugging, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to use protractor elementExplorer and not sure why I can't do it (I'm using Mac).

according to the documentation - http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/debugging I'm going to the protractor directory (use/local/bin) and type

```
node ./bin/elementexplorer.js
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/bin/bin/elementexplorer.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

any help?
thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `cd` into the `protractor` directory:

```
cd node_modules/protractor
node ./bin/elementexplorer.js
```

where `node_modules` in your case should be under `/usr/local/lib/`.

Comment: I have used the cd but apparently not to the correct folder. but now I have.  thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you have protractor installed globally as the docs at https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/ suggest you should be able to start `protractor --elementExplorer` anywhere and then issue commands such as `browser.get('http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/` as per the api at https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api

You can check your protractor install and version by doing `protractor --version`

Current verison is 3.0.0

Comment: As of version 3.2.2, the suggestion, if you try to run elementExplorer directly, is: `Please use "protractor [configFile] [options] --elementExplorer" for full functionality`.  It will work with or without the configFile.

Comment: The gotcha (for the current Protractor version 4.0.9) for Angular 2 projects will be launching without a configuration file will assume a root element of 'body'. You could override this in `elementExplorer` with `browser.rootEl = ''`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already in `protractor/bin` directory try,

```
node elementExplorer.js
```

The best way to access `elementExplorer` is (if protractor installed globally):

```
protractor --elementExplorer
```

(If protractor installed in a specific folder), try:

Go to the specific folder, then:

```
node_modules/.bin/protractor --elementExplorer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows, try `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin`

Here you can find elementexplorer.js

You can do `node elementexplorer.js` it will start selenium standalone server and it will open empty browser.. Here you can test your desired web page.